# Why do we give shankha dhwani at the beginning of the pray?

Tags: identification-request, prayer

What are the important rules to follow up if we keep a shankha at home?

What can we do/get from a shankha?

Comment: Read in some book, sound produced by Shanka is "AUM ॐ". This might be the reason.